# Operator between two Hilbert spaces that preserve inner product must be linear

Tags: functional-analysis

The Question is: If $M$ and $N$ are Hilbert spaces and $U : M \to N$ is a surjective function such that $\langle Uf ,Ug \rangle = \langle f, g \rangle$ for all vectors $f$ and $g$ in $M$, then $U$ is linear.

So to prove the result is that equivalent to showing boundedness of $U$ and then from the fact that any Unitary operator is linear?

Comment: Is that meaningful to show that $U$ is "bounded" if you do not know whether or not $U$ is linear?

Comment: Clearly, $$\Vert U(f)\Vert=\Vert f\Vert\tag{1}$$ then by [Mazur-Ulam's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) $U$ is affine. Substitute $f=0$ in $(1)$, then $U(0)=0$, hence $U$ not only affine but linnear.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to expand
$$
               \|U(f+g)-U(f)-U(g)\|^{2}
$$
into 9 inner-product terms involving $U$ applied to one of $f+g$, $f$, $g$ in the first coordinate with another such term in the second coordinate. Asumming $(Uf,Ug)=(f,g)$ for all $f, g \in X$, then $U$ can be removed from both coordinates of all 9 terms, resulting in the trivial identity
$$
         \|U(f+g)-U(f)-U(g)\|^{2}=\|(f+g)-f-g\|^{2}=0.
$$
So $U$ is automatically additive, meaning that $U(f+g)=U(f)+U(g)$. If $\alpha$ is a scalar and $f \in X$,
$$
\begin{align}
      \|U(\alpha f)-\alpha U(f)\|^{2}
         & =(U(\alpha f),U(\alpha f))-\overline{\alpha}(U(\alpha f),U(f)) \\
         & -\alpha (U(f),U(\alpha f)+|\alpha|^{2}(U(f),U(f)) \\
         & = (\alpha f,\alpha f)-\overline{\alpha}(\alpha f,f)-\alpha(f,\alpha f)+|\alpha|^{2}(f,f) = 0.
\end{align}
$$
So $U(\alpha f)=\alpha U(f)$. Therefore, $U$ is linear. (If $X$ and $Y$ are real spaces, ignore the conjugation, and the above continues to hold.)